# Can NHibernate save a collection without an iterator?

Tags: nhibernate, collections, save

Simple question: can NHibernate save a collection without an iterator? For example:

```
var list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(1000 items);

session.Save(list);
```

Or do I have to do `foreach` over the list?

Comment: You should use Stateless Session
Check out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860256/c-sharp-nhibernate-save-list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple question - simple answer. AFAIK no - you have to iterate. In fact it is faster if you keep flushing and clearing the session time after time like it is told in the NHibernate Docs about batch processing:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.count;i++)
{
  session.Save(list[i])
  if(i % 20 == 0)
  {
    session.Flush();
    session.Clear()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not much more work, just wondering if it can save me a few lines of code.